# OrientDB 3.0.6 is throwing an asynchronous transaction error? why?

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to parse an insert a CSV into a graph database in OrientDB 3.0.6.
The csv file have 25000 documents with some attributes.
When I try to run the parser, I get this error:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot execute the request because an asynchronous operation is in progress. Please use a different connection
DB name="sadosky"
at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.baseNetworkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:249)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.networkOperationRetryTimeout(OStorageRemote.java:214)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.networkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:243)
```

This is the script that load a part of the data.

```
private void parseEtiquetas() {
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(classLoader.getResource("CETA/CETA_set_de_entrenamiento.csv").getFile()));
        reader.skip(1);
        String[] docLine;
        int i = 0;
        Transaction t = sm.getCurrentTransaction();

        System.out.println("Leyendo los datos y calculando los TF...");
        while ((docLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(""+i+"-------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("    Doc: "+docLine[ID_NORMA]);


            // procesar el documento para todas las etiquetas
            // System.out.println("" + docsSize + " " + nextLine[ID_NORMA] + " " + nextLine.length);
            Documento doc = getDocumento(docLine[ID_NORMA], t);

            if (doc != null) {
                System.out.println("Etiquetas: " + docLine[ETIQUETAS]);
                String[] etiquetas = docLine[ETIQUETAS].split(",");
                for (String etiqueta : etiquetas) {
                    etiqueta = etiqueta.trim();
                    System.out.println("--->"+etiqueta+"<");
                    // verificar si existe en la base
                    Etiqueta e = getEtiqueta(etiqueta, t);
                    if (e == null) {
                        System.out.println("Etiqueta nueva: " + etiqueta);
                        Etiqueta et = new Etiqueta(etiqueta);
                        e = t.store(et);

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("etiqueta.size: "+(e.getDocs()!=null?e.getDocs().size():0));
                    }
                    e.addDoc(doc);
                    t.commit();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR AL PROCESAR ID_NORMA: " + docLine[ID_NORMA]+". EL DOC NO EXISTE!!!");
            }

            System.out.println("cerrado trasacción...");

            System.out.println("cerrada.");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Documento getDocumento(String docId, Transaction t) {
    Documento ret = null;
    List<Documento> ld = t.query(Documento.class, "select from Documento where id_doc = ?", new Object[]{docId});
    if (ld.size() > 0) {
        ret = ld.get(0);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The SessionManager (sm) is a class that wrap the connection to the database. The parameter are this:

```
sm = new SessionManager("remote:127.0.0.1/sadosky", "root", "toor", 100, 1000)
            .setActivationStrategy(SessionManager.ActivationStrategy.CLASS_INSTRUMENTATION, true);
```

I could not find what is wrong in Orient 3.  It fail with that error after import 15 records. Always 15 record but not fail at the same point. Sometime if fail in the commit, some time fail in the query. Its not clear and I could'n trace it.
This code work fine with OrientDB 2.2.29.
It seems is something with the OrientGraph transaction.

The Transaction class handle the connection to the database and do some other stuff. This is the relevant part:

```
OrientGraph orientdbTransact;

/**
 * Devuelve una transacción ya inicializada contra la base de datos.
 *
 * @param sm
 */
Transaction(SessionManager sm) {
    this.sm = sm;
    orientdbTransact = this.sm.getFactory().getTx();
    this.objectMapper = this.sm.getObjectMapper();
}

...
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcelo D. Ré, so the problem is present only from version 3.0, have you try Orientdb 2.2.36?

Comment: No. The last version I had downloaded of version 2 was 2.2.29. We are working with 3.0.6 now but since the error was not clear, I decided to test it against 2.2.29 and it work. 
I continued processing the documents on 2.x version since is not a core problem, but I need to fix it in 3.x
I will download 2.2.36 to see what happens.